shinyFiles: Front anwesome not correspond to a know icon #120
I was using Mac OS Intel Chip.
I was trying to use Rstudio to run. cronR add-in but receive this message and then can not run cronR.
It just run 1 time then done.
The 'name' provided ('clock-o') does not correspond to a known icon.
The 'name' provided ('load') does not correspond to a known icon.
The 'name' provided ('delete') does not correspond to a known icon
I use this version and all packages are updated.
frontawesome_0.5.2 shiny_1.8.1.1
[enter image description here].
(https://i.sstatic.net/KPWvt81G.png)
Help me to run cronR please
